# ResourceBundle.getBundle(class,locale) don't get default Bundle

Tags: java

I have a very strange behavior with ResourceBundle.getBundle on both Java7 and Java8 on my Machine (Windows 7 64Bit) and am perplexed.

I try to get the MyRessource Bundle (wich extends RessourceBundle) for the choosen Locale.
Here is the simple code (shortend and simplified):

Default RessourceBundle class:

```
public class MyRessource extends ResourceBundle {

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(final String key) {
        if (key.equals("submit")) return "submit";
     return null;
    }
}
```

German RessourceBundle  class:

```
public class MyRessource_de extends MyRessource {

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(final String key) {
        if (key.equals("submit")) return "absenden";
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then i want to retrieve the German Bundle:

```
    final ResourceBundle bundle_DE = 
          ResourceBundle.getBundle(MyRessource.class.getName(), Locale.GERMANY);
    LOG.debug("Bundle {}", bundle_DE);
    LOG.debug(bundle_DE.getString("submit"));
```

Output is:

> Bundle com.example.MyRessource_de@6cf82c7d
>
> absenden

Now the same with another Language, this should return the Default Bundle:

```
    final ResourceBundle bundle_EN =
          ResourceBundle.getBundle(MyRessource.class.getName(), Locale.UK);
    LOG.debug("Bundle {}", bundle_EN);
    LOG.debug(bundle_EN.getString("submit"));
```

But the output is:

> Bundle com.example.MyRessource_de@6cf82c7d
>
> absenden

The Same cached Bundle was returned.
I tried to clear the cache with ResourceBundle.clearCache() with no success.

When I implement another Language-Bundle and asked for it i get it, but i dont get the Default-Bundle Class.

I have no idea why Java is behaving this way and will be happy of any answer.

On other Machines the code works as intended.

BTW: My Windows System Language is de.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String, java.util.Locale, java.lang.ClassLoader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ResourceBundle javadoc:

> getBundle uses the base name, the specified locale, and the default
>   locale (obtained from Locale.getDefault) to generate a sequence of
>   candidate bundle names. If the specified locale's language, script,
>   country, and variant are all empty strings, then the base name is the
>   only candidate bundle name.

In other words, as it can't find a MyResource_UK resource bundle, it uses the system default to generate a candidate bundle name before it tries using just the base name (and in your case, succeeds in finding the German bundle).

Comment: Thank you very much, set Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK) and it works. I would vote this answer up but I have not the reputation for it.